# I want to extract a specific string from another excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code, but I want to set it up so that, if cell A1 = apples, then it will go to the other workbook and find the word apple and copies that value to my original worksheet.
EG.

Workbook (1)

A1 = APPLES
A2 = PEARS

Workbook (2)

A1 = APPLES __B1 = PIE

A2 = PEARS ___B2= JUICE

Workbook(1) will get the match the values from Workbook (2) and bring the values from column "B" over to Workbook (1) column "B"

I hope that makes sen

```
If .SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
    Application.Workbooks.Open .SelectedItems(1)

    Set xAddWb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    Set xRng1 = Range("A4:E50")
    xWb.Activate

    Set xRng2 = Range("A1")
    xRng1.Copy xRng2

    xRng2.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.AutoFit

    xAddWb.Close False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code .. Similar to your issue

```
Sub VLOOKUP_Closed_Workbook()
Dim wbk         As Workbook
Dim ws          As Worksheet
Dim sh          As Worksheet
Dim i           As Integer
Dim sFolder     As String
Dim fName       As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    sFolder = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\"
    fName = Dir(sFolder & "ClosedWB.xlsm")
    Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(sFolder & fName)
    Set sh = wbk.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With ws.Range("B1:B" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[ClosedWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),""Not Found"")"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    wbk.Close False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: yes it is similar to my issue, i want to know how to chose which columns i can extract and if i can extract multiple columns at the same time and put it into an array?

Comment: this macro that im building if for work. we have a spread sheet that had a tone of emails so wanted to build something that can help extract the emails. each row has a unique code and there are 3 columns that have emails (column E/G/I). I also want to have the emails be put into an array if possible

Not sure if im asking for to much

Answer (score 0):

This code helps a lot, i have a look up value but i need to extract 3 columns of information. but each time i use this code it keeps asking me to select folder but i want to do this only once. In addition i want to put the looked up value in an array if possible.

```
Set wsk = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With wsk.Range("B1:b" & wsk.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[ClosedWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$A:$i,5,FALSE),""Not Found"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With


With wsk.Range("C1:c" & wsk.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[ClosedWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$A:$i,9,FALSE),""Not Found"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With

With wsk.Range("D1:D" & wsk.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    .Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,[ClosedWB.xlsm]Sheet1!$A:$i,7,FALSE),""Not Found"")"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```